# How to create a Must Not Match attribute for email address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, data-annotations

i am using data annotation to validate my properties, below are the properties for my page

```
public string YourEmail{get;set;}
public string AnotherEmail{get;set;}
```

my requirement is that both email id should not be same

please suggest what should i use from data annotation to solve this issue

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement IValidatableObject interface in your model and add method Validate in your model.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
      List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

      if (string.Equals(this.Email1,this.Email2,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
          validationResults.Add(new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage.EmailError, new string[] { "Email ID" }));
      }

      return validationResults;
}
```

Or You can create the custom dataannotation as per your requirement. Please refer below URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx