# First name and Last name must not match validation mvc4

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

can someone please tell me how to write validation for "first name and last name must not match".

my model code is

```
public string firstname{get; set;}
public string lastname{get; set;}
```

Can we use 'compare' attribute to compare these values

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Must Not Match attribute for email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783390/how-to-create-a-must-not-match-attribute-for-email-address)

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786251/opposite-of-compare-data-annotation-in-net

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
[NotEqualTo("lastname")]
public string firstname{ get; set; }
public string lastname{get; set;}
```

References: [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3 - PART 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)
and
[StackOverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786251/opposite-of-compare-data-annotation-in-net)

The StackOverflow link has a lot more types of annotations that could be useful. Hope this helps!